# Spring WebFlux Broken Stream Error Handling

Tags: server-sent-events, spring-webflux

I'm struggling to find any good examples on how to implement error handling with Spring WebFlux.

The use case I want to handle is notifying HTTP clients that a stream has terminated unexpectedly. What I have found it that with the out of the box behaviour, when a stream is terminated, for example by raising a RuntimeException after x items have been processed, is handled too gracefully! The client is flushed all items up until the exception is raised, and then the connection is closed. As far as the client is concerned the request was successful. The following code shows how this has been setup:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getItems(ServerRequest request) {

        Counter counter = new Counter(0);

        return ServerResponse
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                .body(operations.find(query, Document.class, "myCollection")
                        .map(it -> {
                            counter.increment();
                            if(counter.getCount() > 500) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("an error has occurred");
                            }
                            return it;
                        }), Document.class);

}
```

What is the recommended way to handle the error and notify the HTTP client that the stream terminated unexpectedly?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you'd like to communicate that failure to the client. Should the client display some specific error message? Should the client reconnect automatically?

If this is a "business error" that doesn't prevent you from writing to the stream, you could communicate that failure using a specific event type (look at the Server Sent Events spec).

Spring WebFlux supports `ServerSentEvent<T>`, which allows you to control various fields such as event, id, comment and data (the actual data). Using an `Flux::onErrorMap` operator, you could write a specific `ServerSentEvent` that has an `"error"` event type (look at the `ServerSentEvent.builder()` for more).

But this is not transparent to the client, as you'd have to subscribe to specific events and change your JavaScript code otherwise you may display error messages as regular messages.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. Let's say in the case of a back end mongo server connection going down, I would want to be able to notify  the client that an error has occurred and it can then retry as configured. In a non-reactive system this might have been communicated with a 500 status code. Would you recommend a server sent event again in this scenario and would the error not cause the stream to close before an error event could be pumped out?

Comment: Having discussed the requirements further, one solution that has been suggested is to signal success or failure using trailing HTTP headers. Is there a mechanism to set these with WebFlux on stream completion or on error?

Comment: No, trailing headers aren't supported in Spring WebFlux currently. I don't know if those are compatible with SSE in the first place.

Comment: We aren't currently using SSE's. The trailing header would be used in conjunction with an Application Stream + JSON for example.

Comment: Please create an issue on jira.spring.io if you'd like to get trailing headers support. I'm not sure if that's possible consistently as I don't know if servers (Tomcat, Undertow, Jetty) support that natively or with Servlet. Also, if the error is I/O or response body related, you might not be able to properly write to the response those trailing headers anyway.